# Is it possible to look within the at element in pages?

Tags: groovy, geb

is it possible to look for elements only within the "At-Element" ?

Example Page:

```
  class SearchDialogPage extends Page {

    static at = { $('div', class: 'modalOverlay').has('div', class: 'contentbox__title', text: 'Search for Company') }

    static content = {
       nameTextline { $('div').has('label', text:'Name').$('input') module TextInput }
   }    
} }
```

I find more than one element for nameTextline, so i want to tell the Page, that it has to look into the div-Element declared in the "at" field.

Comment: You could try `at().$('div').has('label', text:'Name').$('input') module TextInput` -- never tried it though 

Comment: How about some feedback, Mr. "Sensei"?

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, `at` is not a content element but a boolean condition, i.e. whatever code you have inside there will be evaluated as a "Groovy truthy" value. You should define your element in the `content` section, then refer to it from your `at` condition, not the other way around.